# .NET Core Web Api - Writing an update method for an entity - Should I pass whole object, or just fields that need updated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I am writing an API in c# using .net core 3.1 Web API that exposes some create and get methods for entities and using EFCore to store these in my DB.  I've also started writing some update methods on the controller for changing parts of these entities.  For example, I have a CreatePerson() method that accepts a PersonDTO that I map to a domain object to save in the DB.

My problem is that I am not sure of the best practise for the UpdatePersonName(ExternalPersonNameV1) method.  This will be a partial update to the Person entity.  My two scenarios are

```
public class ExternalPersonNameV1
    {
        //public ExternalLookupItemV1 Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public string Fullname { get; set; }

        [StringLength(256)]
        public string AlternativeName { get; set; }
    }
```

1. Force the consuming user to send the whole object to the API and any fields that are missing are unset in the DB.  If they dont pass the AlternativeName property or pass *null* as the value, the value will be unset in the DB.
2. Force the user to only pass the values in which they want to be updated and any values that are not sent to the api will remain untouched.  If they wish to unset a value in the DB, they can pass the property with *null* value and it would therefore be unset.
3. Any other suggestion?

Apologies if this question isn't formed very well.  This is the first question I've had to ask here so open to suggestions.  Thank you

Comment: In the REST world there is the request method PATCH you might want to look at. That would be some kind of a standard way of doing this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH And it means sending some kind of diff to the server to be applied to the resource instead of the complete resource.